# Generating graphs for given degree sequence in Python or R

Tags: python, r, graph-theory

I am trying to learn if in Python or R, there exist within the graph-theory related modules features that would enable one to start from a degree distribution (or expressed as a sequence once we set the number of vertices), and generate (random) graphs that satisfy the prescribed degree sequence.

As an example, we might be given the following distribution: `p=(0.179,0.49,0.34)` which are the probabilities of degree values `1,2` and `3` respectively. So we can set the number of vertices, `n=500,` map `p` to a degree sequence `deseq` list: filled with `0.179*n` times of `1,` and so on for the rest.

*Any pointers towards previously discussed cases for such problems or library suggestions would be very helpful.*

Comment: Very interesting, but I think it's too precise to have a specific module to create that. But you can create a list of degrees from your distribution, then generate a graph from this sequence, using the configuration model : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much have you already researched on the topic but there is a pretty wellknown package in R and module in Python called [igraph](https://igraph.org/r/doc/). It might have what you seek for.

Comment: @BenBolker I can do that, but is it ok that I would be answering my own question?

Comment: yes; it's actually encouraged to answer your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @BenBolker Ta-da :)

Answer (score 4):

*Here's an attempt to answer my own question after having learned how to use igraph in R and Python for generating the desired type of graphs.*

### [**In R:**](https://igraph.org/r/)

For the purposes of this example, let's suppose the following degree sequence: total nodes `n=20,` `5,10` and `5` nodes with degrees `1,2,` and `3` respectively. We create the degree sequence using `c()` and `rep().` Then we'll use `sample_degseq()` from `igraph` to generate a graph corresponding to the above degree sequence. Then we'll draw its degree histogram to sanity check.

First install and call the igraph module in the R console using:

```
install.packages("igraph")
library(igraph)
```

Now we can proceed as described:

```
degreels <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,10),rep(3,5))
graph <- sample_degseq(degreels, method="simple")
degreehist <- hist(degree(graph))
is.connected(graph)
```

[image]

### [**In Python:**](https://igraph.org/python/)

Now let's do the exact same thing with the igraph module in Python:

To install [see here.](https://igraph.org/python/#pyinstall)

```
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degcounts = [5,10,5]
degreels = []
for i in range(len(degcounts)):
    degreels += degcounts[i]*[i+1]

graph = ig.GraphBase.Degree_Sequence(degreels,method="simple")
plt.hist(graph.degree())
plt.show()
```

and the obtained histogram:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what this is for, but graph theory is pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, the [networkx](https://networkx.org/) package also provides what you are looking for.

In particular, the [functionalities regarding random graphs from degree sequences](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html?highlight=degree%20sequence#module-networkx.generators.degree_seq) (e.g. `configuration_model` with the idea from @Alex_6's comment) might be helpful.